# How do I include the index 'title' in a kibana url?

Tags: kibana

Prior to Kibana 6, I used to be able to programatically construct a url for a Kibana query for a particular index, where the index was specified by its name/title i.e. `logstash-*` or `my-index-*`.

A constructed URL would be something like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5601/app/kibana#/discover?_g=(time:(from:now-1h,mode:quick,to:now))&_a=(query:(language:lucene,query:'my search goes here'),index:'my-index-*')
```

Since Kibana 6, this no longer works as the 'index' appears to require an index ID(?) value such as `3dbd5d60-163c-11e9-8130-471e0fe97583`.

For example, this would work:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5601/app/kibana#/discover?_g=(time:(from:now-1h,mode:quick,to:now))&_a=(query:(language:lucene,query:'my search goes here'),index:3dbd5d60-163c-11e9-8130-471e0fe97583)
```

However, I have no way to know that value when the url is constructed.

Does anyone know if the index name/title can still be used in the url (obviously it would use a different key like `index_title:'my-index-*'` for example)?

Failing that, can Kibana be queried itself to reveal an index ID, given an index name/title?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can use the `index pattern` on the URL anymore, you need to use the `ID` associated to that `index pattern`.

To get the `ID` you can use the query below on dev tools:

```
GET .kibana/_search
{
   "_source": ["index-pattern.title"],
   "query": { "term": { "type": "index-pattern" }}
}
```